# Insert only if unique using knex

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, asynchronous, knex.js

I am writing a Node.js Script which accepts an array of objects that represent a different devices recording different measurements. I would like to store information about the device in a PSQL database using Knex.js, but only want to store the device information from objects representing a new/unique device.  Validation of the device_id before insert seems to work as long as the same device shows up in different POST requests. But when the same device shows up 
in the same POST request it seems as if the asynchronous nature of the program causes the validation to occur before insertion is complete.

I've tried to make the script call two separate async-await functions (one to validate and the other to actually insert) but not sure if this is the easiest approach or if I did it right since it failed anyways.

```
app.post('/testsite', (req, res) => {
  const data = (req.body.measurements);
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    database.select("device_id").from("device_info").where("device_id", data[i].device_id)
      .then(MatchList => {
        console.log(MatchList);
        if (MatchList.length === 0) {
          return database('device_info')
            .returning('device_id')
            .insert({
              device_id: data[i].device_id,
              device_name: data[i].device_name,
              site_id: data[i].site_id,
              site_name: data[i].site_name
            })
            .then((newdevice) => {
              console.log('inserted device id', newdevice);
            });
        }
        return;
      });
  }
});
```

I expect it to not insert when the validation fails, but it seems like the validation never fails even when it should and I get this error:

```
Unhandled rejection error: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "device_info_pkey"
```

Comment: Which validation?

Comment: @alfasin The validation is when I select all the entries in the database where the device_id === data[i].device_id and ensure that the length of all these entries is 0. Basically that no such device exits. If and only if this is true then there should be an attempt to insert.

Comment: Are you using [knex](http://knexjs.org)?

Comment: @technogeek1995 yes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to solve the issue. Essentially just using async await on the search and insert was not enough as the for loop would still move on to the next element. To get around this I made the POST request call an async function.

```
app.post('/testsite', (req,res) => 

{ const data = (req.body.measurements);

    postfxn(data); } )
```

This function awaits every iteration of the for loop.

```
async function postfxn(data){

for(let i =0; i<data.length; i++){
     await insertdevice(data[i]); }
  }
```

the insert device function then uses async await to search for the device and insert if it is not in the database already as suggested by technogeek1996's answer.

Hope this helps others with similar issues

Comment: That still wouldn't work because `app.post('/testsite', (req,res) =>` does not use `async`, which it **must** to use an async function. Also, you're not using `await` when calling `postfxn`, which means it wouldn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the issue is due to the asynchronous nature of knex, or if the issue is something else. However, I re-wrote your code to use async/await syntax to make it more readable. I also am just checking if device comes back as null instead of an array since I added `.first()`. Could you check and see if `device` gets console logged when you call this function?

```
app.post('/testsite', async (req, res) => {
  const data = (req.body.measurements);
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const device = await database
      .select('*')
      .from('device_info')
      .where('device_id', data[i].device_id)
      .first();
    console.log(device);
    if (device) {
      const newDevice = await database
        .from('device_info')
        .insert({
          device_id: data[i].device_id,
          device_name: data[i].device_name,
          site_id: data[i].site_id,
          site_name: data[i].site_name
        })
        .returning('*');

      return newDevice;
    } else {
      return device;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: So I had to move the contents of the for loop into a function called postfxn and then define that function as an async function outside of the POST request in order to use the await key word. However this still did not solve the issue. The console log comes back as undefined and if I remove the .first() it comes back as an empty array

Comment: It comes back as undefined even when you're expecting a value to be there? Are you sure that `data[i].device_id` is not undefined?

Comment: It is definitely defined as I use data[i].device_id for the actual insertion and that works. The fact that removing .first() just returns an empty array even when the PSQL database shows that the insertion was completed makes me believe that since Javascript is asynchronous the for loop moves on to the next query before the previous device can be inserted

Comment: The way this is written above (with async/await), asynchronous should not have any issues. `await` is a blocking call, which makes the code appear like it's synchronous code. Can you edit your question and do a `\d device_info` from `psql` interpreter?